# CSS minification error in npm run build [vue.js]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cssnano

Im receiving this error everytime I try to run 'npm run build' and I dont have any css file.

> ERROR  Error: CSS minification error: Unexpected ":" found.. File: css/app.86f0ef2e.css
>
> Error: CSS minification error: Unexpected ":" found.. File: css/app.86f0ef2e.css
> at C:\Users\LesterKingsley\OneDrive\Desktop\vuewuna\dos\node_modules@intervolga\optimize-cssnano-plugin\index.js:106:21
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)

I'm new to vue, I don't have a clue to solve this problem.

Comment: You have a syntax error in some CSS. Can't help you without seeing it

Comment: yeah thanks its a stupid mistake, wrong syntax in my style thanks bro!

Comment: _"I dont have any css file"_ do you have any `<style>` blocks in your Vue components?

Comment: yeah bro i just panicked, i think its the problem in the node_modules thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same error last week, and this is my solution to it. I'm not sure if it's going to work for you though.
What I did basically was these;

- I found and removed the file that course the error (in my case public/css/argon.css) then I cut out all the codes inside of that file and saved.
- Then I ran npm run build and it built successfully.
- After the build process had completed, I then pasted the codes inside of the file (in my case dist/css/argon.css) and the vuejs created css.
  That solved the problem.
  Pls give a thumbs up if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sometimes in the `::v-deep` label:

```
// WRONG:
::v-deep(.some-class) { ... }

// READY:
::v-deep .some-class { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please **comment** all your internal css. This work for me successfully.

I too did not have any external css file. But the issues were in my internal files.

This is the line that cause the error `text-align: calc();`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error.
For me the problem was this:

```
input['text'], 
input['email'] {
    user-select: initial;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).